# Coloring In between CGPaths

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I am building a drawing type tool into my app.

It takes a touch points from the user and draws lines between the points. If the user creates 3 touch points or greater, it joins the last point to the first point.

An extract of the code is :

```
startPoint = [[secondDotsArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    endPoint = [[secondDotsArray objectAtIndex:(i + 1)] CGPointValue];
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context,(CGRectMake ((endPoint.x - 5.7), (endPoint.y - 5.7)
                                                   , 9.0, 9.0)));
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I wish to "color in " the area contained within these paths. 
What should I look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `CGContextFillPath` API. You should be careful of how you define the path, though:

- Start by calling `CGContextMoveToPoint` on the initial point
- Proceed by drawing all segments except the closing one with `CGContextAddLineToPoint`
- Close the path with `CGContextClosePath`. Do not add line to point on the final segment.

The call of `CGContextFillPath` will produce a path colored with the fill color that you have previously set.

Here is an example:

```
CGPoint pt0 = startPoint = [[secondDotsArray objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pt0.x, pt0.y);
for (int i = 1 ; i < noOfDots ; i++) {
    CGPoint next = [[secondDotsArray objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, next.x, next.y);
}
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, I am just double checking before I attempt this that I was clear in the asking of my question. I have the iPhone drawing blue lines between the points touched. What I want to do is color in the area between these 3 lines. Is this still ok?

Comment: @Ríomhaire If the three lines represent a closed path (i.e. a triangle) then yes, `CGContextFillPath` will color in that triangle.

Comment: I think I have followed you're steps correctly. Is there a conflict within my method? I have the revised method here on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wgu3vkUP). Cheers @dasbinkenlight

Comment: @Ríomhaire You are not doing it right - there should be no other operations on the context in between you drawing line segments. In particular, there must be no calls to `CGContextMoveToPoint` in the loop, and no calls of `CGContextStrokePath`. If you need to draw circles and whatnot, you should do it in a separate loop. See the update for a skeletal example.